# PHP to view PDF on web page and disable user to download

Tags: php, pdf

I'm going to write a site that lets users to view pdf files but I don't want them to save the files to their own hard drive due to the copy right law. I'm researching how to view it by using PHP, but I have no idea how to disable user not to download the files.

Actually, I want to use JavaScript to disable this action, but I get suggestions from other people not to do so because it's annoying to user.

So any suggestion or help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can't absolutely prevent someone from downloading content to their hard drive. The simple fact that they're viewing the content from your website means that they've somehow downloaded it already.

Comment: javascript can be turned off in any browser, so never rely on that for something critical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 01**

Implementing that useing [Google books](https://books.google.com/)

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:0px" src="https://books.google.com.kh/books?id=e5MkzETNcsgC&lpg=PP1&dq=typography&pg=PA11&output=embed" width="500" height=500>
</iframe>
```

[image]

In above image it shows `Embed` that will be the code. And **Download or Print option is not available on this**. **Google dosc can prevent download but its allow to `Save to Drive` option**. Then in drive **i can download it**. ***But [Google books](https://books.google.com/) not allow any of that***.

in view

[image: 02]

**Method 02**

Using [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/)

Right click on `pdf` and goto **Share**(below image)

[image: 03]

Then go to **Advanced option** in left bottom

[image: 05]

Tick Both check boxes. After copy `embed` link and paste it to your `src`. **No download and Save drive option is not allowed**

> **Note: *Method 01* and *Method 02* is Tested**

Answer (score 6):

### USE CSS `opacity: 1.0` with a `<div>` positioned over your content...

You could output the pdf using `<object>` or `<iframe>`, then place a  with absolute position and use z-index to cover your pdf.  Use the css `opacity: 1.0`.

Now when users try to click or copy, they get nothing because they are really clicking on a blank `<div>`!!!!

Its a hack, but it works!  The user will be able to read the content, they could take a screen shot, but they won't be able to actually copy the text and paste it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent your visitors from downloading, copying or scrapping anything you're outputting to their browsers. If they can view it they can always screenshot it. Which brings in the optimal solution to your problem: Simply offer image copies of your documents instead of actual PDF files. You can convert / mass convert PDF files to JPEG easily with Photoshop.

Comment: I really want to do like http://books.google.com.kh/books?id=e5MkzETNcsgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=typography&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QkSjT8cli-SsB9K5gfUN&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=typography&f=false.

Comment: Google does what i suggested above but just programatically. Check this: http://books.google.com.kh/books?id=e5MkzETNcsgC&pg=PP1&img=1&zoom=3&sig=ACfU3U1S8ck1p6fn2yn-RahxRAB7HqSomQ

Answer (score 1):

I hope I am not very late to reply. But here's is something you can do to prevent the users. Use iFrame to display your PDF and make sure that you are displaying using Google. I used the following code :

```
 <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_tutorial.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Here you can simply change the `url=http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_tutorial.pdf` and replace it by your own URL where you kept your PDF.

Comment: Users can view the page source code and get the direct link to the pdf no?
Cause the iframe source literally has the direct file path in it

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<iframe  src="test1.pdf" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="position:absolute; clip:rect (190px,1100px,800px,250px);">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<embed src="http://URL_TO_PDF.com/pdf.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" width="500" height="500">
```

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the requirement to not download the PDF file?