# How to embed pdf file into books.google.com?

Tags: html, pdf, iframe

Hi I have problem that I want to embed my website pdf file in books.google.com by iframe. I have tried [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441937/php-to-view-pdf-on-web-page-and-disable-user-to-download/31934852#31934852) but I dont know that how to give my site link to iframe

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:0px" src="https://books.google.com.kh/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=website.com/test/CV.pdf" width="500" height=500></iframe>
```

So any suggestion or help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are missing the closing `</iframe>`. other than that, it should work when using a valid link. If you can provide the link you are trying to use, we can assist further.

Comment: Sorry. Its not real mistake. I just missed it while writing question

Comment: I have edited question

Comment: Can you provide the direct link to the pdf?

Comment: The pdf link you have in the iframe goes to a 404 error

Comment: softbroz.com/test/CV.pdf

Comment: @MosesDavidowitz I have commented

Comment: Do you necessarily want to use books.google? Or the purpose is to embed the PDF on your site?

Comment: books.google.com  prevent from downloading. Thats why its purpose

Answer (score 1):

It does't seem that you ever uploaded your PDF to books.google. You will have to do so in order to get the embed code to include in you site.
With the direct link you provided, you can embed that like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.softbroz.com/test/CV.pdf" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

If you want to embed a PDF from books.google, you will have to upload the PDF first, then follow these instructions:

> **Embed a PDF located on google drive**

1. Select your PDF in Google Drive. In the toolbar click on the eye
   icon to preview the PDF.

[image]

2. You need to pop out the PDF by clicking on the Pop-out icon (square
   with an arrow).

[image]

3. The more options icon (3 dots) has the option to embed the PDF.

[image]

4. Copy the embed code. Use this in your site. Notice the default height and width in the code of
   640 by 480 pixels. You may want to edit those values to show the
   size you want in your embed.

[image]

Comment: It does not prevent it from downloading

Comment: Ahh, I see, did you upload the PDF on books.google? Can you provide the link to that?

Comment: I haven't uploaded. Is this necessary?